# LilyPond - compile midi output only

Tags: midi, lilypond

Is there a way/command-line option, to make [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org) only compile the `\midi {}` output, even though there is a `\layout {}` block in  the `source.ly` file?

Just been going through [The Command Line Options](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/command_002dline-usage#basic-command-line-options-for-lilypond) in the [Documentary](http://lilypond.org/website/manuals.html) and the only thing I can find for "midi" is the option to change the output file extension with:

```
midi-extension  "midi"  Set the default file extension for MIDI output file to given string.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `-dbackend null` to your command, which will suppress the output of a printed score. Alternatively, you can use `-dno-print-pages`. A midi file will still be generated, as long as a `\midi{}` block is defined in your score.

So, you command should look like this:

```
lilypond -dbackend=null my_file.ly
```

Or like this:

```
lilypond -dno-print-pages my_file.ly
```