# LilyPond - supress/skip MIDI generation

Tags: lilypond, engraving

When I work on my [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org) scores, especially in the end when I just tweak on some graphical settings, it would be quite nice if it was possible to skip the Midi generation, even though it is not very time consuming. Is this possible from the command-line in a similar way then to [skip the pdf generation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/92741/lilypond-compile-midi-output-only)?

Again I have not been able to find something in the [LilyPond Documentary](http://lilypond.org/website/manuals.html) section about the [Command-Line Options](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/command_002dline-usage#basic-command-line-options-for-lilypond).

---

**Update:**

if I had the `\midi {}` block only in one line, I could simply comment it out by using `sed` from the command-line, with something like: `sed -i 's/\\midi\ {}/%&/g' file.ly`. While the option `-i` stands for *inplace-editing*. Without the option `sed` is going to print to `stdout`. You could also use [wildcarts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) to batch process a bunch of files: `*.ly` would process all files ending with `.ly` in the current directory.

It would get more difficult, if the `\midi` block was bigger then a single line, like here with setting the tempo:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\score {
  <<
    \new Staff = "celloI" \with { midiInstrument = #"cello" }
    \relative c {
      \clef bass
      c4( d e f
      g1) \bar "|."
    }
    \new Staff = "celloII" \with { midiInstrument = #"cello" }
    \relative c, {
      \clef bass
      c4( d e f
      g1) \bar "|."
    }
  >>
  \layout {}
  \midi {
    \tempo 2 = 120
  } 
}
```

Comment: I fear there is indeed no command line option for this. The only way I can think of is to comment out the Midi block.

Comment: @JasperHabicht ok thanks. On a UNIX/LINUX system one could got for something with `sed` like `sed -i 's/\\midi\ {}/%&/g' file.ly` to comment out the `\midi` block. Though this would only work if the the block did not have multible lines.

Comment: If the block has multiple lines, you could perhaps define a macro that contains these lines and put this macro into the midi block, which would then only have one line. Might not work in every case though ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht maybe this, with an example, is the appropriate answer :-)

Comment: Do you have a snippet with a bit of your code, especially that from the midi block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, LilyPond does not provide a command line option for this. The only way I can think of is to comment out the `midi` block. However, your approach using `sed` is very promising!

To avoid the problem of your `midi` block containing several lines, you could write a macro that contains the whole `midi` block with all your settings and place this macro into your `score` block. You should then be able to use `sed` to replace this single line from your code.

I was not able to test this with `sed`, but if you change your code as follows, it should work with something like `sed -i 's/\\mymidi/%&/g' file.ly`:

```
\version "2.19.83"

mymidi = \midi {
    \tempo 2 = 120
  } 

\score {
  <<
    \new Staff = "celloI" \with { midiInstrument = #"cello" }
    \relative c {
      \clef bass
      c4( d e f
      g1) \bar "|."
    }
    \new Staff = "celloII" \with { midiInstrument = #"cello" }
    \relative c, {
      \clef bass
      c4( d e f
      g1) \bar "|."
    }
  >>
  \layout {}
  \mymidi 
}
```

If you have more than one `score` block, you would need to create several macros for the `midi` blocks and change the `sed` command accordingly.

The above code, however, seems to work only as from version 2.19.

Comment: This setup works pretty well for me. Sure I have quite a lot of `\score` blocks, but I could use something like `\mymidifirst` `\mymidisecond` etc. and then use sed to just comment the line out with an "add before pattern match" like: `sed 's/\\mymidi/%&/g' *.ly`

Comment: for some reason I get `02.ly:23:3: Fehler: syntax error, unexpected OUTPUT_DEF_IDENTIFIER` when truing to compile this.

Comment: You are right. It seems that the code only works with the newest version of LilyPond.

Comment: this is kind of weird since it works like: `macro = \relative { c d e f g }` or `macro = \markup { "some text" }` it only does not work like: `macro = \midi {}`...